# Use of calculus in calculating maximum angle at which the parabolic path is covered by the body, is maximum.

Tags: calculus, integration, physics

A body is projected from a plane surface at an angle theta. Find the value of theta at which the parabolic path travelled by the body is maximum.And also find the velocity with which it should be projected.

This is a physics problem. 
 1. The only problem is that it   doesn’t have physics. Only maths.
 2. The problem uses some calculus  , (integration,mostly) 
 First broke the x and y direction velocity and integrated it with w.r.t time. But I couldn’t proceed further because a relation came in logarithm with base e.

So please can anyone help.

Edit: Removed classical physics tag.

Comment: "because a relation came in logarithm with base" in a classic way with no [air resistance force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_(physics)) and with constant $g$ there is no need to complex formulas because trajectory is simple a parabola, there's no $\log$. Can you please edit the question to show how far did you get and the log with base also? Thanks

Comment: "And also find the velocity with which it should be projected". Ummm.... the highest possible velocity, right?

Comment: Yes @David G. Stork.

Comment: @Alexey Burdin actually it is base e. I have edited it.

Comment: "Find the maximum value of theta at which the parabolic path travelled by the body is maximum". Ummmm.... why find the "maximum value of theta" rather than the "minimum value of theta" or, heck, "the value of theta"?

Comment: Anyway, the classic formula have no logs. @JAOFELIX , or do you mean [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+sqrt%281%2B4*x%5E2%29+dx)? $\sinh^{-1}$ does indeed have logs, yes. Please include the calculations in the question so we can see how far did you get and can help in the exact place of difficulcy. Thanks

Comment: @ David G. Stork due some network issues at my end the edit might have been delayed. I apologise for the inconvenience caused. It is the minimum value of theta.

Comment: @JaoFelix:  I suspect there is a language problem here.  You are incorrect to ask "the minimum value of theta."  Why the *minimum* value of theta?  Please explain why you want the "minimum" value of theta.

Comment: @ Alexey Burdin thanks for your suggestion but right now at present situation of mine I am having no convenient software to type the method I proceeded with.

Comment: You need no software, MathJax simply to be enclosed in dollar signs.

Comment: @ David G. Stork as I stated earlier not all edits are being saved due to unhealthy connection at my end. I once again apologise.

Answer (score 1):

This is a standard problem. Assuming standard conditions (gravity being a constant, in the -ve y direction), we can write the velocity of the object as a function of time as

$$v(t) = v_0\cos\theta \textbf{i} + (v_o\sin\theta - gt)\textbf{j}$$

Now, the distance travelled along the trajectory at a particular time instant is given as

$$ds = \sqrt{dx^2 + dy^2}
\\ = \sqrt{(v_0\cos\theta)^2 + (v_0\sin\theta - gt)^2}dt$$

Hence, the total length traversed in the air is given by

$$S = \int_0^{t_f}\sqrt{(v_0\cos\theta)^2 + (v_0\sin\theta - gt)^2}dt$$

Now, this is a function of both the initial velocity, and the angle of projection. Hence, to maximise it, we need to set the partial derivative w.r.t angle of projection to 0

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial \theta} = \frac{\partial t_f}{\partial \theta}.{}\int_0^{t_f}\frac{-2gt\cos\theta dt}{2\sqrt{(v_0\cos\theta)^2 + (v_0\sin\theta - gt)^2}} = 0$$

Now, time of flight is given from the other kinematic equation, as

$$t_f = \sqrt{2v_0g\sin\theta}
\implies \frac{\partial t_f}{\partial\theta} = \frac{v_og\cos\theta}{\sqrt{2v_0g\sin\theta}}$$

Put it all together and can you proceed?

Comment: thanks a lot i was able to understand it.

Comment: One issue with this, is that it will be maximised when $\theta = 0$ as then technically the ball will never land. So there will need to be a viscous damping force (air resistance) to get a proper angle and to make physical sense, but that problem would be much harder, and honestly is better off solved via numerical methods and MATLAB or something equivalent